# Java: ChaCha20 w/ Poly1305 as MAC for general purpose file encryption

Tags: java, encryption

I need to use ChaCha20/Poly1305 for general purpose encryption and decryption of any data from any source (the same way we use I/O streams, ex. CipherInputStream).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32672241/using-bouncycastles-chacha-for-file-encryption) already asks if it's possible to use Bouncy Castle's ChaCha20Poly1305 class to process data but only TLS transactions seem to be supported.

So now I'm left with pure ChaCha20 (ChaCha20Engine). I would like to know if writing my own encrypt-then-MAC scheme is a good idea or not, so that I get exactly what I need.

tl;dr Is it OK to write my own ChaCha20/Poly1305 encrypt-then-MAC mode of operation ?

Comment: I don't think you wanted to ask whether *"[it is] OK to write my own ChaCha20/Poly1305 encrypt-then-MAC mode of operation?"*. Generally, we recommend not to roll your own encryption, so the answer would be **no**. Questions that can be answered with a simple yes or no are not very interesting. It seems to me, the proper question would be, *how can I combine ChaCha20 and Poly1305 in BouncyCastle for general purpose encryption?*

Comment: BouncyCastle is under MIT license, so you can easily take that class and throw away all the references to TLS.

Comment: But then if I modify the class to make it general purpose, wouldn't that be equal to rolling my own crypto ?

Comment: Sure, but it is less error prone (security-wise) if you remove some functionality instead of building it from scratch. The border between *rolling your own crypto* and *using existing crypto* is a moving target and there is no real consensus where the border actually is. You can hire a security consultant to look over the code if you're not sure.

Comment: That is true. However, the modified class takes an input as a whole and then processes it. This renders input streaming impossible.

Comment: Nevermind, I sorted it out. You can check the class I've come up with [here](https://github.com/Serphentas/CryptoClient/blob/master/src/internal/crypto/CPCipher.java).

Comment: That looks fine to me. You might want to post a proper answer with that code.

Comment: I have to make it pass test vectors first, then I will update this question with the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Java 11** adds a "ChaCha20-Poly1305/None/NoPadding Cipher
It is now possible to use without any third party libraries or some other magic -->

Here´s a reference **Implementation**

**ATTENTION this Implementation uses a non-random Nonce and should NOT be used except for Testing purposes**:

```
package chaCha20Poly1305Encryption;

import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class ChaCha20Poly1305 {

public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] data, SecretKey key) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException {
    if(key == null) throw new InvalidKeyException("SecretKey must NOT be NULL");

    byte[] nonceBytes = new byte[12];

    // Get Cipher Instance
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("ChaCha20-Poly1305/None/NoPadding");

    // Create IvParamterSpec
    AlgorithmParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(nonceBytes);

    // Create SecretKeySpec
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "ChaCha20");

    // Initialize Cipher for ENCRYPT_MODE
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivParameterSpec);

    // Perform Encryption
    return cipher.doFinal(data);
}

public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] cipherText, SecretKey key) throws Exception {
    if(key == null) throw new InvalidKeyException("SecretKey must NOT be NULL");
    byte[] nonceBytes = new byte[12];

    // Get Cipher Instance
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("ChaCha20-Poly1305/None/NoPadding");

    // Create IvParamterSpec
    AlgorithmParameterSpec ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(nonceBytes);

    // Create SecretKeySpec
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), "ChaCha20");

    // Initialize Cipher for DECRYPT_MODE
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivParameterSpec);

    // Perform Decryption
    return cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SecretKey key = ChaCha20Poly1305KeyGenerator.generateKey();

    String testMessage = "hallo!";
    byte[] encryptedBytes = encrypt(testMessage.getBytes(), key);
    String decryptedMessage = new String(decrypt(encryptedBytes,key));
    System.out.println("testMessage: " + testMessage);
    System.out.println(key.getAlgorithm() + " SecretKey: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key.getEncoded()));
    System.out.println("encryptedBytes: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedBytes));
    System.out.println("decryptedMessage: "+ decryptedMessage);

}
}
```

And the corresponding Key-Generator:

```
package chaCha20Poly1305Encryption;

import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;

public class ChaCha20Poly1305KeyGenerator {
    public static SecretKey generateKey() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("ChaCha20");
        //Keysize MUST be 256 bit - as of Java11 only 256Bit is supported
        keyGenerator.init(256);
        return keyGenerator.generateKey();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SecretKey key = generateKey();
        System.out.println(key.getAlgorithm() + " SecretKey: " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key.getEncoded()));
    }
}
```

Code used from my Github GIST:
https://gist.github.com/eXspir3/7a0821a6cfdb0495ccc3e69b475a61b9

Comment: At long last, I can mark this as answered after 3½ years ! Thanks

Comment: A Nonce (Number only used once) must always be unique. Reusing the nonce even once compromises the security of the encrypted data. `byte[12]` fills the nonce with all zeros, meaning it's the same each time. Read here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32075/what-happens-if-a-nonce-is-reused-in-chacha20-poly1305

Comment: Hi there! This is very true! This Implementation was meant for test usage only - will clarify